# Scam wallet token recovery

Tags: solidity, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, flashbots, hack

How to build a code to recover the remaining coins from a hacked wallet

Assume a hacker has compromised the wallet and automatically withdraws some funds how do I recover the remaining funds and there is no
gas to move the funds

Comment: You will need to replicate the steps that the hacker did to hack the contract. You will need to find the vulnerability too. With a smart contract many things can go wrong, so without a code example, it's not easy to tell you where the vulnerability might be.

Comment: Does this help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/112097/75850